# Set consecutive numbers to specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
| DesignKey |            DesignTypeGuid            | DesignNumber |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
|      2312 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            3 |
|      2313 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            7 |
|      2314 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            8 |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
```

So I get `DesignNumber` values  with query like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentChangeOrderDesignNumber INT = 
              (SELECT [DesignKey], [DesignNumber] 
                FROM [Design] 
                WHERE ParentDesignKey = @DesignKey
                AND DesignTypeGuid = @COTypeGuid ORDER BY DesignKey);
```

That I want to do is to get this data and set new `DesignNumber` values starting from 1, so my desire result should be:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
| DesignKey |            DesignTypeGuid            | DesignNumber |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
|      2312 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            1 |
|      2313 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            2 |
|      2314 | 4FB560B0-E867-46B2-B116-338AD48C97AC |            3 |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------------+
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `SELECT` query, you would use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT [DesignKey], [DesignNumber],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentDesignKey, DesignTypeGuid ORDER BY DesignNumber) as new_DesignNumber 
FROM [Design] 
WHERE ParentDesignKey = @DesignKey AND
      DesignTypeGuid = @COTypeGuid
ORDER BY DesignKey;
```

If you want to update the values, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT d.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentDesignKey, DesignTypeGuid ORDER BY DesignNumber) as new_DesignNumber 
      FROM Design d
      WHERE ParentDesignKey = @DesignKey AND
            DesignTypeGuid = @COTypeGuid
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET DesignNumber = new_DesignNumber;
```

Comment: Awesome... Fast question. What about if I have a number... supossing number 5 and I want to continue from this number in order to set 6,7,8 as DesignNumber is it possible to set a starting number with CTE instead start from one?

Comment: You would add "5" to the result of `row_number()`.

Comment: You mean  `row_number(5)`? because it throws me an error of `row_number` takes 0 arguments

Comment: @Jonathan . . . `(5 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentDesignKey, DesignTypeGuid ORDER BY DesignNumber)) as new_DesignNumber`